# Code to trim part of a text file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a situation where I am given a text file with text formatted as follows:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\report2011.docx: My Report 2011
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\newposter.docx: Dinner Party Poster 08
```

How would it be possible to trim the text file, so to trim the ":" and all characters after it.

E.g. so the output would be like:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\report2011.docx
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\newposter.docx




Current Code:

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"c:\output.txt"))
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\filename.txt");
                Regex reg = new Regex(@"\w\:(.(?!\:))+");
                List<string> parsedStrings = new List<string>();

                while (sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(reg.Match(sr.ReadLine()).Value);
                }
            }

        }
```

Not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int index = myString.LastIndexOf(":");
if (index > 0)
   myString= myString.Substring(0, index);
```

Edit - Added answer based on modified question. It can be condensed slightly, but left expanded for clarity of what's going on.

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"c:\output.txt"))
 {
      using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"input.txt"))
      {                    

          string myString = "";
          while (!sr.EndOfStream)
          {

                myString = sr.ReadLine();
                int index = myString.LastIndexOf(":");
                if (index > 0)
                    myString = myString.Substring(0, index);

                sw.WriteLine(myString);
           }
       }
  }
```

Comment: Let's say the input is `C:\Temp\blah.txt: entered at 12:00`. What then?

Comment: @Anthony: The OP wasn't detailed enough about input requirements to make it possible to avoid all possible issues.

Comment: @Anthony - Answer is based on OP's sample. Happy to change if it's possible for `12:00` to occur.

Comment: Nitpicking, but the OPs sample was clearly more about the second ':' than about the last ':'.

Comment: @keyboardP Hi, thank you for your input, please could you provide an example in the context of a button, as I get output as "The string "my.name" doesn't exist in this context

Comment: @James - Do you mean in a button event handler?

Comment: @James - I've edited my answer. That code can go inside your button handler. I assume that you'll never have a `:` other at the end? (except straight after `docx:`).

Answer (score 1):

*Edited*

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("yourfile.txt");
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\w\:(.(?!\:))+");
List<string> parsedStrings = new List<string>();
while (!sr.EndOfStream) 
{
    parsedStrings.Add(reg.Match(sr.ReadLine()).Value);
}
```

Comment: @FlyingStreudel I think its because I am dealing with a text file with a number of strings, where as you example is only taking one string

Comment: @FlyingStrudel, I did not downvote you, but I assume it's because you're using a regex for a simple string problem.

Comment: @James - It is trivial to adapt this to reading text from a file... Ill edit it. @jb - One regex for 1,000,000 lines is nominally different than string.split(':'), actually I think its more efficient.

Comment: @FlyingStrudel  I get: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Regex' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Limited\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 44 13 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: you need `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` at the top of your code file

Comment: @FlyingStreudel Ahh thank you, the last error seems to be Error 1 'System.IO.StreamReader' does not contain a definition for 'EOF' and no extension method 'EOF' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.StreamReader' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Limited\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 47 24 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: @FlyingStreudel, I had to test it for myself, this Regex is roughly 7 times slower than keyboardP's string methods. I love Regex quite a bit, but you gotta admit the overhead kills you.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel Just tried code, doesn't seem to work, I updated my initial post with your code I have implemented

Comment: What isn't working? I just tested and confirmed what @jb mentioned, the .Net regex is outrageously slow. But the code does work :/ I would implement @keyboardP's solutions assuming that you can never have an additional ':' after the second one.

Comment: Although, depending on the string, having it seek from both sides for the offending ':' can be faster than the LastIndexOf() when the number of characters on the right half exceed the number on the left.

Answer (score 0):

sure. while reading each line, do a

```
Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(0,line.IndexOf(": "));
```

Comment: For `C:\Temp\blah.txt: hi mom`, the output is `C`.

Comment: Your adjustment makes it `C:\C`.

Comment: changed the 0 to a 1. Thanks!

Comment: Changed to use same drive letter in case they change in the file

Answer (score 0):

i'd use the answer given here [Code to trim part of a text file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283586/code-to-trim-part-of-a-text-file-in-c) and find the 2nd occurrence and then use it in substring.

```
var s = @"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\report2011.docx: My Report 2011";
var i = GetNthIndex(s,':',2);
var result = s.Substring(i+1);


public int GetNthIndex(string s, char t, int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == t)
        {
            count++;
            if (count == n)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is being done where the files are supposed to exist, you could handle this taking into account any colons in the (what I assume is) description by checking for the existence of the files after you get the index of the colon.

```
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        files.Add(@"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\report2011.docx: My Report 2011");
        files.Add(@"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\newposter.docx: Dinner Party Poster 08");
        files.Add(@"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\newposter.docx: Dinner Party: 08");

        int lastColon;
        string filename;
        foreach (string s in files)
        {
            bool isFilePath = false;
            filename = s;
            while (!isFilePath)
            {
                lastColon = filename.LastIndexOf(":");
                if (lastColon > 0)
                {
                    filename = filename.Substring(0, lastColon);
                    if (File.Exists(filename))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(filename);
                        isFilePath = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", s);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
more faster:

```
 string s = @"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\report2011.docx: My Report 2011";
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(s) + s.Split(new char[] { ':' }) [1];
            Console.WriteLine(path); //C:\Users\Admin\Documents\report2011.docx
```

you need import System.IO

Answer (score -1):

you could use split:

```
string[] splitted= myString.Split(':');
```

Then you get an array where you take the first one.

```
var mySplittedString = splitted[0]
```

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if you need more information on this.

EDIT: In your case you get an array with the size of at least 3 so you need to get splitted[0] and splitted[ 1]

Comment: He'll always get at least 3 given his samples. `C:\the\path: more text`. Want to update your post?

Comment: You're right. If we take the example from Anthony (C:\Temp\blah.txt: entered at 12:00) it would be four. So it is at least three based on James examples. I'll update. Thx.